# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running spring application

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-rest

I am new to Spring.

Below is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>kar</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <description>Demo</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <spring.version>4.2.0.RC2</spring.version>
    <spring-hateoas.version>0.19.0.RELEASE</spring-hateoas.version>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Gosling-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-data-releasetrain.version>

    <jackson.version>2.6.1</jackson.version>
    <querydsl.version>3.6.5</querydsl.version>
    <springfox.version>2.0.3</springfox.version>

    <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
      <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
      <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>jitpack.io</id>
      <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0.M1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
      <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.bedatadriven</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
      <version>jackson-datatype-jts-1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

When i run the application, i am getting the response as,

```
2015-09-06 12:34:51.620  INFO 15591 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/kar/demo/backend/target/classes/, file:/home/kar/demo/backend/target/test-classes/, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.12/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.1/jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.1/jackson-core-2.6.1.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.0.RC2/spring-core-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.0.RC2/spring-web-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.0.RC2/spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/2.4.0.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.1/jackson-annotations-2.6.1.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/github/fge/json-patch/1.7/json-patch-1.7.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/github/fge/jackson-coreutils/1.6/jackson-coreutils-1.6.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/github/fge/msg-simple/1.1/msg-simple-1.1.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/github/fge/btf/1.2/btf-1.2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-core/2.3.2.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.0.RC2/spring-tx-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.19.0.RELEASE/spring-hateoas-0.19.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-data-commons-1.11.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/atteo/evo-inflector/1.2.1/evo-inflector-1.2.1.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.23.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.23.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.6/aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.6/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.0.RC2/spring-jdbc-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.23/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.23/tomcat-juli-8.0.23.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.10.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.0.RC2/spring-orm-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.0.RC2/spring-aspects-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-hal-browser/2.4.0.M1/spring-data-rest-hal-browser-2.4.0.M1.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.0.RC2/spring-beans-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.0.RC2/spring-context-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.0.RC2/spring-expression-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.2.7.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.7.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.7.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.0.RC2/spring-aop-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-test-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/mockito-core-1.10.19.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/4.2.0.RC2/spring-test-4.2.0.RC2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc41/postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-spatial/4.3/hibernate-spatial-4.3.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.0.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/postgresql/postgresql/8.4-701.jdbc4/postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/postgis/postgis-jdbc/1.5.2/postgis-jdbc-1.5.2.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.13/jts-1.13.jar, file:/root/.m2/repository/com/github/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts/jackson-datatype-jts-1.0/jackson-datatype-jts-jackson-datatype-jts-1.0.jar]
2015-09-06 12:34:51.625 ERROR 15591 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/EnumTranslationConfiguration
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:291)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:231)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:336)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:248)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:231)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:269)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:658)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:504)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at kar.demo.Application.main(Application.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.EnumTranslationConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 common frames omitted

2015-09-06 12:34:51.626  INFO 15591 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3b2c72c2: startup date [Sun Sep 06 12:34:51 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-09-06 12:34:51.627  WARN 15591 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3b2c72c2: startup date [Sun Sep 06 12:34:51 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:399)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:951)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:910)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at kar.demo.Application.main(Application.java:59)
```

Kindly advise to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why do you use snapshot versions instead of final, finished, supported versions? I would almost understand your desire to use versions that are not released *yet*, but you're using spring 4.2.0.RC2 although the 4.2.1.RELEASE version is out. My advice: stop using the spring snapshot repo, and stick to final release versions. Also, use compatible versions: you're using spring-data-rest-core 2.3.2 with spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue on one of my Spring boot 2.0.1 projects with [spring-boot-starter-hateoas](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-hateoas/2.0.1.RELEASE) added.

I just added the [evo-inflector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.atteo/evo-inflector/1.2.1) dependency to resolve:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atteo</groupId>
    <artifactId>evo-inflector</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot works best with version of Spring it was designed for. You are having Spring Boot version 1.2.5.RELEASE (which uses Spring 4.1.x). You also overridden this Spring version with 4.2.0.RC1.

Just remove `spring.version` property and try again.

Comment: I have removed the spring.version but still getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/EnumTranslationConfiguration
error @lkrnac